# Email address validation using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on email validation for a login page using jQuery. The problem I am facing is only the else part is getting executed and not if part. Below is the code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#my-input').focusout(function () {
        emailValidate();
    });

    function emailValidate() {
        var reg = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;
        var email = $('#my-input').val();
        if (reg.test('email')) {
            console.log('correct');
            $('#my-input').css('border', '2px solid green');
            $('#span1').css('display', 'none');
        } else {
            $('#my-input').css('border', '2px solid red');
            $('#span1').css('display', 'block');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be `email` as Variable, not as String

```js
var email = $('#my-input').val();
if ( reg.test(email) ) {
```

Here's a slight remake with the mentioned fix.
It uses a CSS class to determine the styles. JS is only used to toggle that `has-error` class from the common parent label element.

It also doesn't uses IDs. `data-validate` is a far more flexible option!

```js
const has = {
  value: (val) => val.trim().length > 0,
  email: (val) => /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/.test(val),
  // add more validators here
};


jQuery(function($) { // DOM ready and $ alias inn scope

  function validate() {
    const isValid = has[this.dataset.validate](this.value);
    $(this).closest("label").toggleClass("has-error", !isValid);
  }

  $("[data-validate]").on("focusout", validate);
  
});
```

```css
/*QuickReset*/ *,*::before,*::after{margin:0; box-sizing:border-box;}
body {font:16px/1.6 sans-serif;}


label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}

label input {
  flex: 1;
}

label.has-error {
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-image-slice: 1;
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(to right, red, fuchsia);
}

label .error {
  color: red;
  display: none;
}

label.has-error .error {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <span class="placeholder">Name:</span>
  <input type="text" name="name" data-validate="value">
  <span class="error">Name cannot be empty</span>
</label>
<label>
  <span class="placeholder">Email:</span>
  <input type="text" name="email" data-validate="email">
  <span class="error">Invalid Email address</span>
</label>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

PS: makes no sense to use "green" colors to mark something *OK* in UI. It's the same logic in which you would never show an alert box saying *"Hey! Your email is correct!"*. Users presume it's *correct* if not marked otherwise.